# Mocking API responses

Tags: frontend

Say I’m working on a project that communicates with the API `www.example.api`. I’m implementing a new feature, that requests data from the api endpoint `www.example.api/feature`. This endpoint will in the future return the json
`{ “keyOne”: “valueOne”,  “keyTwo”: “valueTwo”}`, however since the backend team hasn’t finished the endpoint yet, it is still just returning the current value of `{ “keyOne”: “valueOne” }`. Can I somehow mock the response coming from the API and append the new key to the old response, so that I can work on the feature even though the backend team hasn’t updated the endpoint yet?

Comment: Yes, in the function where you make your api call replace: `const response = await yourApiCall()` with `const response = {“keyOne”: “valueOne”,  “keyTwo”: “valueTwo”}`. Aka just hardcode a mock value in there. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yeah why not just preserve the current state of what the backend is returning and once the response comes though simply merge the response object with the mock object.

Answer (score 0):

Possible by local your mock server using 'express'

Simulate old server by OPEN API call

```
https://catfact.ninja/fact
```

It is a supposed old server, it will return two keys (`fact` and `length`), and the values are randomly changed every API call.

```
{
  "fact": "Of all the species of cats, the domestic cat is the only species able to hold its tail vertically while walking. All species of wild cats hold their tail horizontally or tucked between their legs while walking.",
  "length": 210
}
```

In the mock local server will add your required key/value ("keyTwo": "valueTwo")

#### Demo code

Save as `mock-server.js`

```js
const express = require("express")
const axios = require("axios")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.get("/fact", async (req, res) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        url = 'https://catfact.ninja/fact',
        config = {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
            }
        }
    )
    // data = {
    //     "fact": "cat description - random change the content every API call.",
    //     "length": 210
    // }
    res.json(Object.assign(data, {keyTwo: "valueTwo"}))
})

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Listening on : 3000") })
```

#### Install Dependencies

```
npm install express axios cors
```

#### Run it

```
node mock-server.js
```

#### Access the mock-server

```
http://localhost:3000/fact
```

#### Result

```
{
  "fact": "Cat's urine glows under a black light.",
  "length": 38,
  "keyTwo": "valueTwo"
}
```

[image]

So your frontend code switch,
from `https://catfact.ninja/fact`
to `http://localhost:3000/fact`